# How to create CheckStyle Check for validating Annotation Fields

Tags: checkstyle

```
@WebService(serviceName="TestImpl",
targetNamespace = "http://example.org"
)
public class TestImpl implements Test{
```

If my Test class is something like above my check should verify if the targetNamespace value always starts with "http://"

If no existing checks can do that how should my Custom check look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Checkstyle out of the box by applying a [RegexpMultiline](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpMultiline) check like this:

```xml
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format"
        value="(?s)@WebService\s*\(.*?targetNamespace\s*=\s*&quot;(?!http:\/\/).{7}"/>
    <property name="message"
        value="Target namespace must start with &quot;http://&quot;"/>
</module>
```

Here's an [explanation of the regex](http://regex101.com/r/wL9gP1).